# Can't access Desktop on Mac due to permission issues: How do I fix it through terminal?

Tags: permission-denied

How do I change access to desktop permissions from the command line on a Mac? I am getting the message. The folder Desktop can't be opened because you don't have permission to see its contents.

I need my desktop access permission back